# ASP.Net Grab contents of External website directory and store inside of listbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, listbox, uri

I have gotten this to work with populating the listbox from files from a directory on my server using

```
Dim diFiles As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/pdfs/"))
```

and then inserting them into lstFiles using

```
lstFiles.DatasSource = diFiles.GetFiles("*.pdf")
```

and lastly entering them into a new listbox using

```
For Each fri In lstFiles.DataSource
    ListBox1.Items.Add(fri.ToString)
Next
```

However now I need to do the same thing using a external websites directory, however when I try to enter the external servers directory over server.mapPath("http://example.com/pdfdirectory/") it gives me an exception that URI's are not valid in DirectoryInfo.

I have tried

```
For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("http://example.com/pdfdirectory/") 'put your directory path here
        Try
            ListBox1.Items.Add(File.ReadAllLines(f)(0)) 'Read the first line of each file
        Catch ex As ArgumentNullException
            ListBox1.Items.Add("[NO DATA]")   'If no Data catch Error 
        Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
            ListBox1.Items.Add("[NO DATA]")   'If no Data catch Error
        End Try
    Next
```

However the above gives me an URI exception aswell.

The last thing I have tried is WebRequest but I do not know how to get the directory into the listbox.

```
Dim request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/pdfdirectory/"), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    Using reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim body As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
```

And I do not want to download the files first. I just want the listbox text to be of the file names on the external server.

I should mention the server already has the directory files available to be seen. Index of /pdfdirectory with the PDF listing

Comment: I doubt you can, this would be a huge security issue. You can only access the file system of the local machine

Comment: @zgood I should mention the server already has the directory files available to be seen. Index of /pdfdirectory with the PDF listing

Comment: Is this located inside your local network?

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b no, that is why I would like a solution that can use URI